# Wordpress Redirect: Default Password Reset URL

Tags: php, functions

I would like to redirect the default wordpress password reset url /end-point. So the url before the password is reset.

/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword

redirect to
/password-reset/ (which is aalready setup)

I have created a custom page, so any user querying the old url will be redirected to the new page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a filter to change the lost password url. Try this :

```
add_filter( 'lostpassword_url',  'my_lostpassword_url', 10, 0 );
function my_lostpassword_url() {
    return site_url('/password-reset/');
}
```

**Note** : You can place code in  functions.php or make plugin (Recommended).

Comment: Thank you very much! This change the global hook and works. My only issue is that if anything else references the old url, then i need that to redirect.

Comment: As I understand now,You want redirect if some one access url it go to new url

Comment: @Stefano Please use this plugin : http://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/